# C++ Invalid pointer values

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to know which pointer values are invalid so i would not have to allocate new memory just to mark special chunk states(Memory consumption is critical). So i could use them for special states like

- **0x00000000** - would mean chunk is not loaded
- **0x00000001** - would mean chunk is empty
- **0x00000002** - chunk is full. And when some real stuff needs to be saved to the memory i would do new Chunk(...);

Comment: Can you not have a structure with the pointer and an enum?

Comment: NULL is the only value I have ever consistently used and therefore know is an invalid pointer value. I would recommend what chris said - use an enum value to indicate the status of the pointer.

Comment: The only guaranteed-to-be-invalid pointer in C++ is `nullptr` (of which the numerical value is not specified). Yeah, smells like an XY problem so I echo what @chris suggested.

Comment: I second what chris said, but you'll have to say more about the platform you're targeting. C++ doesn't make any claims like 0x00000002 is an invalid address :)

Comment: I am working in visual studio 2008 - Windows x86.

Comment: The problem is every bit counts. I have 4096 chunks in blocks. Each block can be 24B in size when allocated. And i have more than 4000 blocks loaded. If i add enum i would add extra 4B per chunk which is 65MB of enums.

Comment: @BlackCat, Make the underlying type `char` and you're down to 1B extra instead of 4. I can't help but feel a compiler might pad the structure in that case, though.

Comment: Do not do this, even `NULL` is a valid pointer in certain contexts. OpenGL, for instance, uses `void*` as an offset into memory allocated and managed by the driver. The address **0** is perfectly meaningful there.

Comment: What if i have bitset for whole block? 2*4096 bits(which gives me 4 states)? Block is actually array of pointers to chunks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest just using a struct that contains a pointer and an enum. But if for some reason that's inconvenient, just allocate some small structures and use their addresses just to indicate magic pointer values. (Of course, don't ever free them.)

You can also use the address of static objects. Like this:

```
static int chunk_not_loaded_i, chunk_empty_i, chunk_full_i;
void *chunk_not_loaded = &chunk_not_loaded_i;
void *chunk_full = &chunk_full_i;

if (some_chunk == chunk_not_loaded)
    ...
```

Comment: This is actually very good idea! Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

Assigning exact values to the pointer is quite unstable and error-prone. That way, your code would be tight to exact hardware architecture(s). For example, some platforms have 0x00000000 as absolutely valid address.
So the fact that address is assigned or not is not related to numeric value of the pointer (at common case).

Answer (score 0):

`0x00000000` is equivalent to `NULL`, which should be replaced by `nullptr` in C++11 (which does not have a specified numerical value - though, most implementations treat it as 0 to make backwards compatibility easy - that is not guaranteed, though).

It is the only "special" pointer value.  All other values are treated as valid pointer values (meaning attempting to use them would attempt to dereference the pointer - and likely will have bad consequences for values like `0x00000001` or `0x00000002`).  It sounds like you need a container (e.g. pool) that has a state (which could be an `enum` or some other value you desire).  Alternatively, you could use `boost::optional<T>` or `std::pair<T*, bool>` to mark pointers as valid or invalid.

Comment: "All other values are valid pointer values" is wrong; apart from that, it's worth pointing out that the null pointer need not have an actual numeric value zero.

Comment: @H2CO3 valid in that they are not special so attempting to use them would dereference (or attempt to).  I'm open to more precise wording ...

Comment: @H2CO3, Is the following standardese not enough for it to be (evaluate to) 0? *A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.*

Comment: @chris No. A literal 0, when used in a context where a pointer is expected, is only an *indication* of the null pointer. On certain (mostly old) architectures, the actual numerical value of the null pointer is not zero. So `void *ptr = 0;` can result in assembly that looks like `mov r0, 0x7fffffff`...

Comment: @H2CO3, Well, yes, but as far as the language part goes, 0 is the null pointer constant. I just don't see how assuming that while using the language can be affected by the implementation details of how that 0 is transformed when compiled.

Comment: don't write that "0x00000000 is equivalent to NULL" then. "0" means nullptr in pointer context, but it doesn't mean it's going to be represented as 0x00000000.